# Android 2.3.X css font-family fallback not working

Tags: android, css, font-face

I currently have an app with a webview. The webview loads css that determines the specific font each devices should use.

For my iOS devices I use HelveticaNeue CondensedBold since it is included with iOS5+. Since I cannot use this for earlier iOS and Android since it is not a system font I am using Googles OpenSans-CondensedBold.

The issue I am running into is on Android devices using 2.3.X. The font-family fallback is not working at all. Since the HelvelticaNeue font isn't present it just fails and doesn't fallback to the OpenSans which is next in line.

```
font-family: 'OpenSans-CondensedBold', 'Helvetica', 'Arial';
```

If I remove the HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold from the css in the above example, the OpanSans font works on the Android perfectly.

Current CSS Below.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans-CondensedBold';
    src: url('/webfonts/opensans-condbold.eot');
    src: url('/webfonts/opensans-condbold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/webfonts/opensans-condbold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/webfonts/opensans-condbold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/webfonts/opensans-condbold.svg#OpenSans-CondensedBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'OpenSans-CondensedBold', 'Helvetica', 'Arial';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: ** After further investigation, I realized it is defaulting to the system font of the phone. If I change the system font in the settings, the new font from the settings will display.

Comment: USER AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.6; en-us; SCH-I510 4G Build/EP4) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1

Comment: I am doing this for now, even though I hate to. if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)){
 document.body.style.fontFamily = "OpenSans-CondensedBold";
}

Answer (score 0):

you could try to encode the font file as base64 data uri.. sencha touch 2 is doing this also and it seems to work.

to do this upload your font file here http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php
then use the generated code in your CSS like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "My Font";
    src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;base64,[base-encoded font here]) format('woff'), 
         url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,[base-encoded font here]) format('svg'), 
         url(data:application/x-font-ttf;base64,[base-encoded font here]) format('truetype'); 
}
```

in case you're using compass, it appearantly has has [a method](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/inline-data/) to encode the font file on the fly

there's [a related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617306/new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax-using-data-uris-in-compass) question also to this method

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Please consider revising this to include an example of what the OP should do.

Comment: yeah i thought that too, but unfortunately i couldn't find the "add comment" button for the question.. edited the answer though